# Which Javascript framework is the grasshopper app teaching, because I can't find what to practice with on my pc

Tags: javascript, windows, performance, mobile, grasshopper

Which Javascript framework is grasshopper teaching? I have been learning javascript on my mobile phone through the help of an app by Google 'grasshopper',I want to practice on my pc into familiarity but it seems the app is teaching already defined functions that are not part of the original javascript build,I need a way to walk over this problem. Please!

Comment: The [tag:grasshopper] tag you've used doesn't seem to have anything to do with a teaching site.

Comment: I don't see anything in [the FAQ](https://grasshopper.app/faq/) to suggest they're teaching any particular framework. It's not surprising if they give you some helpful utility functions so you don't have to start completely from scratch.

Comment: Ok. I will keep going with the app for now then!

Comment: I think they're using their own functions that are just part of grasshopper, not any particular framework.

Comment: This same issue bugged me, i've been using grasshopper since 2018 and all of a sudden i realized their framework is NOT universal. Lmao. Bummer isn't it?

Comment: Lol. the only thing is that the framework made js seem easy